# giving access to only one object to read a file and write it

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, synchronized

I would like to know if multiple threads try to access a single txt file, how to restrict it?
If thread A tries to access the file till it completes the reading and writing part, other threads must wait. Here is what I tried.

```
package singleton;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
import java.io.*;
class ReadFileUsingThread
{
    public synchronized void readFromFile(final String f, Thread thread) {

    Runnable readRun = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        FileInputStream in=null;
        FileOutputStream out=null;
        String text = null;
        try{
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          File inputFile = new File(f);
          in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
          byte bt[] =  new byte[(int)inputFile.length()];
          in.read(bt);
          text = new String(bt);
          //String file_name = "E:/sumi.txt";
          //File file = new File(file_name);
         // FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("E:/sumi.txt");
          out = new FileOutputStream("E:/sumi.txt");
          out.write(bt);
          System.out.println(text);


       } catch(Exception ex) {
       }  
      }
    };
    thread = new Thread(readRun);
    thread.start();
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ReadFileUsingThread files=new ReadFileUsingThread();
        Thread thread1=new Thread();
        Thread thread2=new Thread();
        Thread thread3=new Thread();

        String f1="C:/Users/Admin/Documents/links.txt";//,f2="C:/employee.txt",f3="C:/hello.txt";
        thread1.start();
        files.readFromFile(f1,thread1);
        thread2.start();
        files.readFromFile(f1,thread2);
        thread3.start();
        files.readFromFile(f1,thread3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not important to the question, but you are creating (and starting) threads in `main` that you don't do anything with -- you are starting new threads in `readFromFile` and replace the reference to the thread passed as parameter.  Seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting way to do it would be to intern the string value of the file's FQN, and then synchronize on it. The more 'traditional' way is to use the `FileChannel` object and lock on it, with other processes simply waiting on the lock, to take their turns.

Caveat : None of these solutions will solve contention between JVM's, or contention between a JVM and other external programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

```
ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

...

lock.readLock().lock();
try {
  //do reading stuff in here
} finally {
   lock.readLock().unlock();
}

...

lock.writeLock().lock();
try {
  //do writing stuff in here
} finally {
  lock.writeLock().unlock();
}
```

Or, for something simpler, you could synchronize on the interned (interning ensures that the `String` object is shared) `String` object that represents that `File`'s full path name:

```
synchronized(file.getAbsolutePath().intern()) {
   //do operations on that file here
}
```

The `ReadWriteLock` approach will have better performance as `Thread`s will be allowed to read the file at the same time while manually synchronizing does not allow this.

Comment: @sahana If you are taking the `ReadWriteLock` approach, the `lock` should be accessible to any `Thread` attempting to access the file and the other parts should be where you are reading/writing to the file. If you are taking the synchronization approach, it should wrap around all of your read/write actions.

Comment: I understood to an extent. Still trying out. Thanks Jeffrey.